# Why my parsing doesn't work?

Tags: java, parsing

I was asked for my homework to make a program wherein the user inputs a Roman numerals between 1-10 and outputs the decimal equivalent. Since I'll be getting a string in the input and an integer in the output, I parsed it, but it won't work. Any ideas why?

```
import java.util.Scanner ;

class Romans {

    static Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in) ;
    static String val = null ;

    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        System.out.print ("Enter a roman numeral between I to X: ");
        String val = s.nextLine();

        int e = Integer.parseInt(val);
    }
    static int getRoman (int e)
    {
        if (val = "I"){
            System.out.print ("1") ;
        }else if (val = "II" ){
            System.out.print ("2") ;
        }else if (val = "III") {
            System.out.print ("3") ;
        } else if (val = "IV") {
            System.out.print ("4") ;
        } else if (val = "V"){
            System.out.print ("5");
        } else if (val = "VI") {
            System.out.print ("6");
        } else if (val = "VII") {
            System.out.print ("7");
        } else if (val = "VIII") {
            System.out.print ("8");
        } else if (val = "IX") {
            System.out.print ("9");
        } else if (val = "X") {
            System.out.print ("10") ;
        }
        return val ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: Look up how to do string comparisons properly.

Comment: Another hint: The same error is repeated around X times :)

Comment: "won't work" is not a suitable description of a problem.

Answer (score 4):

Two points:

- `=` is the assignment operator, not the equality-testing operator (`==`)
- You shouldn't use `==` to test for string equality anyway, as it will only test for *reference* equality; use `equals` to test whether two string references refer to *equal* (but potentially distinct) string objects.

Additionally, you're trying to return a `String` variable as an `int`, *and* you're not even calling `getRoman`...

Comment: How do i call the method? Sorry am still a freshman. Thanks. :)

Comment: @Gen: If you haven't learned how to call a method, you really need to go back to books - Stack Overflow is great for specific questions, but it's *not* good for learning from scratch. Having said that, you *can* just change your `Integer.parseInt` method to a call to `getRoman` instead...

Comment: getRoman(val); and change the signature of getRoman to be getRoman(String val). Also you don't need the parseInt

Comment: Jon Skeet i would read my books if professors provided books for us to read instead of asking us to make a program from scratch and going to class once every month. The education system in my country sucks. But thanks for the suggestion. Stivlo Thanks. :)

Comment: @Gen: There are online Java books, too. The "official" resource are the [Java Tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/). Start with the trails "Getting Started" and "Learning the Java Language".

Comment: "How do I call the method?" You know how to call a method. Hint: You did call `Integer.parseInt`.

Answer (score 1):

I think we can tell you that the correct way to compare Strings is using equals().

You're doing assignments, to compare primitive types you've to use ==, to compare String the equals method.

Example:

if (val.equals("I"))

But also val is not present in the method getRoman().

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to parse val as an int, but its not, its a character.

For such a small sample of chars, its probably easiest to simply create a lookup table, index it on the char.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting any errors?

In your code, you never call the getRoman function. Also, you're using the assignment operator = instead of the comparison operator "I".equals(val) for example.

Comment: How do i call the method? Sorry am still a freshman. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

String comparsion should be done with `equals(String str)` method instead of `==` comparison.
PS. You have `=` instead of `==` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The following statement is an assignment:

```
val = "I"
```

That is definitely *not* what you want to do here.

A comparison is done  with the double equals, but double equals (`==`) compares references but you do not want to do that here either.

You want to use the `equals` method.

```
if (val.equals("I")) ...
```

Make those change everywhere and see how it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

ACtually your main trouble comes from string comparison. In java, = is meant to assign values to variables, == is meant to compare values of primitive types and equals is the way to compare objects, especially for strings.

An alternative to using equals can be to use the JDK internal pool of strings, in this case, you could use == as a comparator.

In your case of parsing roman language numbers, you could also consider using a hashmap to store and retrieve effectively the parsed values of numbers. If you have thousands of comparisons like this to make, then go for identityhashmap.

And last, if you want to do real parsing for all roman numbers, not only the first ones, then you should considering using an automata, i.e. a state machine to parse numbers in a somewhat recursive way, that would be the more efficient model to apply to your problem.

The last 2 remarks are more oriented towards software algorithms, the first two ones are more oriented towards java syntax. You should start to know the syntax before going higher level optimizations.

Regards,
 Stéphane

Answer (score 0):

Aside from what was said above about how your String comparison should use the equals( ... ) function - for example,

```
if ( val.equals("VII") )
```

you also need to provide a return value for your function called getRoman. This function was declared as a function that returns an integer value to the caller, but in the implementation that you have provided, there are no return values (only System.out.println( ... )).

Also, you aren't inputting the correct parameter type - from what it looks like, your function is checking a String to see if it is a certain Roman numeral. So the correct function header would look like this:

```
public static int getRoman(String val)
```

Also, make sure you are actually calling this function in your main() - from what it looks like right now, you aren't even using the getRoman() function.

Hope this helps!